# Android: keep a TextView at the same locaton on a bitmap regardless screen type

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a LinearLayout with a bitmap set as a background. One of the children of this layout is a TextView. This TextView contains some text that must be placed in a fixed region of the bitmap.
To do that I'm using android:paddingLeft attribute. 
Bitmap is defined only for hdpi screen and the padding attributes are given in dp. 

The question is: will the text always match the bitmap for different screen densities?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Also you can try with different dimention files for ldpi,hdpi and mdpi

Comment: the first thing I read is the link above but it doesn't really answer my question. Different dimensions for ldpi hdpi and mdpi is a bit too straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is wrong. Better set background to TextView.

Comment: TextView is displayed only at the small part of the bitmap. Imagine that a bitmap is a picture a car and I want to display some text at the front window

Comment: Answer: Yes it will, but make sure your Bitmap holder has width and heigh set to  wrap_content. You can use 9 patch image to set paddings, and your content will always look the same.